# Brownie Import Error: _PyGen_Send [Ubuntu Jelly 22.04]

Tags: python, ethereum, brownie

I just updated my ubuntu os and after had installed the following:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user pipx
$ python3 -m pipx ensurepath
$ pipx install eth-brownie
```

when i launch the `brownie console` i get the following message:

**Traceback (most recent call last)**:

- File "/home/user/.local/bin/brownie", line 5, in 
  from brownie._cli.**main** import main
- File "/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/**init**.py", line 6, in 
  from brownie.project import compile_source, run
- File "/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/project/**init**.py", line 3, in 
  from .main import (  # NOQA 401
- File "/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/project/main.py", line 44, in 
  from brownie.network import web3
- File "/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/network/**init**.py", line 4, in 
  from .account import Accounts
- File "/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/network/account.py", line 12, in 
  import eth_account
- File "/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_account/**init**.py", line 1, in 
  from eth_account.account import (  # noqa: F401
- File "/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_account/account.py", line 8, in 
  from cytoolz import (
- File "/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/**init**.py", line 3, in 
  from .functoolz import *

**ImportError:** /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: **_PyGen_Send**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing python 3.8 and then ran:

```
pipx install --python python3.8 eth-brownie
```

If you get errors then you may have to run these commands before you install brownie:

```
sudo apt install python3.8-distutils
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So is something related Python versioning. The point is if I go back on py3.8 I can’t create Python venv (only possible with Python 3.10) so I have to manage brownie directly on my local machine